# Multi-Touch Tap Pad Gestures on Synaptics Tap Pad

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

On my previous machine, a Lenovo U400 with a cypress tap pad (R.I.P.), I could swipe left and right with four fingers to show and hide the Unity bar and double tap to switch through open apps. My new machine, an HP Envy 15t slim quad, has a similarly sized synaptics tap pad which I know supports multi-touch but refuses to work the same way. Why is this? How can I get gestures back? There seems to be very little information on multi-touch available on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible due to hardware limitations. According to [the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/HardwareSupport), Synaptics tap pads only support two or three simultaneous touches depending on the model while the Cypress tap pad could obviously detect at least four for the gestures to work properly.